# Can I use a crawling bot to analyze MS Excel files?

Tags: excel

I've been learning more and more about web crawling bots. It's neat stuff and there's a lot of source code available to play with, as well as functional examples.

Can I use something like these bots to analyze a lot (~1000) of MS Excel files for various keywords? 
I don't think this would necessarily be a bot, so what's term for what I'm looking for? 
Are there any good examples of such a thing that you can think of?
Is a grep a good tool for this?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes? Is a web crawler the best thing? Probably not. They are excel files not web pages. You can use VBA or any number of other tools. It depends on how you want to analyse the files.

Comment: I want to search files for keywords and other specific strings, like GPS coordinates.

Comment: When you say VBA, do you mean Visual Basic for Applications?

Comment: Yes, any language which has means to interact with excel would work though. All will require you to code your own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn on indexing for the folder in question, the built-in search function of Windows allows you to do just that.

Comment: Is there any good way to get that search function to output the results to some kind of spreadsheet file (.csv, .xls, etc)?

Comment: You didn't mention that was your goal. In that case I'd advise to write VBA code that opens the files. Note that that would probably only get you Excel files.

Comment: Neat. Thank you very much!